# I am getting a "Fatal Client error; Disconnecting"

Tags: perforce, linuxthreads

I am having trouble with this error when attempting to connect to perforce client

`Fatal client error; disconnecting! write: ...: No space left on device`

I have tried looking into the contents of this "..." folder but there is not much there.

Answer (score 0):

The machine which runs your Perforce server is probably out of disk space.

Do you have an administrator who runs your server? Contact them, and ask them to have a look at the server machine to see if disk space can be freed up.